# react redux render data undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am very new to React-redux applications development so I am trying to code simple worldcup app. Simply my code are;

```
class Teams extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onRequestData();
  }

  renderTeams() {
    const { team } = this.props;
    console.log(team);
            _.map(team, teamList =>
              <Grid.Column
                mobile={4}
                tablet={8}
                computer={8}
                key={teamList.id} >
                <Card >
                  <Image src={teamList.flag} />
                  <Card.Content>
                    <Card.Header>Nationality</Card.Header>
                    <Card.Description key={teamList.id}> {teamList.name} </Card.Description>
                  </Card.Content>
                </Card>
              </Grid.Column>
          );

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Grid>
          {this.renderTeams()}
        </Grid>
      </Container>);
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
console.log("mapPropState", state);
  return {
    team: state.fetchData.teams

  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onRequestData: () => dispatch(fetchResults())
});
```

I can see I fetch the data(with console.log("mapPropState", state) but unfortunately I guess my render method undefined. So nothings work on page and no console error. So where did i do wrong?
Thank You.

Comment: What is the exact error message? And which line is it on?

Comment: One of the biggest problem is, there is no console error... I just see white page.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/CaT375b you can see there what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`team` is undefined when your component is first rendered. I assume that `fetchResults()` calls `fetch()` to make an HTTP request. This will eventually return the data and later you see that `team` has a value. You need to write your component in such a way that it checks if `team` is defined:

```
render() {
return (
  <Container>
    <Grid>
      {this.props.team && this.renderTeams()}
    </Grid>
  </Container>);
```

If you want to get fancy, you can render a spinning circle to indicate that data is loading until you have the data available.

**Note:**

The names `team` and `teamList` seem to be reversed since `teamList` seems to refer to a single team object in the array stored in `team`. I suggest you use `teamList` to refer to the entire array and `team` to refer to individual objects in the array when you map over it.

There is no need to do use `_.map()` because you can just do `teamList.map(team => {/* ... */});`. Also, you need to return the result of mapping over the list:

```
return teamList.map(team => {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Simply "team &&" control works and i'll keep that in my mind what you said. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Ryoush This is a common technique called "conditional rendering". It checks if the first value is "truthy" (often meaning that it is defined) before attempting to render.

Answer (score 2):

Your `renderTeams` function is not returning anything. From the looks of your code, I assume it should be returning `_.map(...)`, correct?